# How to setup Google Analytic goals that go to different URLs?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I would like to setup my form's conversion rate as a goal in my Google Analytics account. The goal is complete when someone enters their information and hits submit. Logically, the "Thank you page" would be the destination URL for the goal. My problem is that the thank you page is outside of the primary domain, for example, my site is:

SiteExampl.com but the Thank you URL is thankyouurl.com

Is it possible to setup a goal like this? If so how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christina, this is a bit tricky situation as it involves cross-domain tracking and the visitor/goal tracking won't be consistent since each site is using its own sets of cookies. To keep this not that complicated and technical (for that purpose, there is a [lengthy documentation by Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain)), I am going to assume that the conversion will be counted as simply the fact that the user pressed button.

You could then setup event tracking and create a new goal with a condition of this event being fired (Type = Event, in *Goal* details then use the same Category/Action/Label as you would you in the tracking code -- see below).

The example of event tracking code: ([see the complete specification for details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide))

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Goal', 'Submit', 'Name']);">Submit</a>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

this is possible . Please execute an Event when submitting the form. Then redirect to the thank you page.

Use form submission position or button click position and then execute the Event Tracking method and pass the related info at that time. Google Analytics give you an opportunity to setup events as Goals. Hence this will be a very easy task.

Event Tracking in Google Analytics:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: I don't think this would work -- it's a different domain, hence a different set of cookies. Much better and cleaner solution would be to use Measurement Protocol and pair CliendID for a given visitor -- this would keep the original campaign source/medium as well.

Comment: in this case you can use campaign tracking in Google Analytics. Then you can keep a track of source and medium also, since your parsing the related parameters. But the related site should have GA installed.If this situation effects to your site, i recommend to use both event tracking and campaign tracking. Then you can compare your  conversions.